# Extreme points in a Polytope

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-programming

Every polytope has a finite number of extreme points.

Is it an half space a polytope ? And if yes which are its extreme points ?

Thanks

Comment: What, precisely, is your definition of *polytope*? (There seems to be more than one out there, and your answer depends on this detail.)

Comment: Intersection of a finite number of half-spaces

Comment: With no clause ruling out $\mathbb R^n$ or the empty set or a single half space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a polytope, it is easily seen to be a special case of polytopes namely a convex polytope. One of the definitions of a convex polytope is a [finite intersection of halfspaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope#Intersection_of_half-spaces). Your polytope clearly satisfies that.

To answer the second part of your question: your polytope has no extreme points. To see this using [this definition of extreme points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point) is easy.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently in some points my book isn't accurate...

Answer (score 0):

For sake of clarity, from the polyhedral theory point of view there is a difference between a polyhedron and a polytope. Both are convex sets, both are the intersection of a finite number of halfspaces, but a polytope is bounded. For example
$$P=\{(x_1, x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2\ |\ x_1+x_2\geq 1, x_1\geq 0, x_2\geq 0\}$$
is a polyhedron, while
$$Q=\{(x_1, x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2\ |\ x_1+x_2\geq 1, x_1+x_2\leq 2, x_1\geq 0, x_2\geq 0\}$$
is a bounded polyhedron, that is a polytope. Thus, I would say that an halfspace is a polyhedron.